# How to define a caching rule in Azure CDN for the root path without rewriting the url?

Tags: azure, caching, cdn

I have a static website in azure that hosts an angular webapp, and I have setup a CDN with **Standard Verizon** pricing tier.

The problem is whenever I deploy a new version, users need to clear their browser cache to see the fresh content and it is annoying.

I would like to do not cache the index.html content which is the response of root path. 
However, Azure does not let me to define a rule so that root path response should not be cached.

If you know how to achieve, it would be great.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible and it is infuriating that you can set cache rules for everything except to root document.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to do not cache the index.html content which is the
>   response of root path. However, Azure does not let me to define a rule
>   so that root path response should not be cached.

If you do not want the root path cache, you could use the global rule instead for a custom rule that applies to all requests. For example, you could set the global cache behavior **Bypass cache**. Then you could set the individual custom rules for other contents required caches. Custom caching rules take precedence over global caching rules, where they apply. If a request matches both conditions, rules at the bottom of the list take precedence over rules at the top of the list. Refer to [this1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-caching-rules#custom-caching-rules-match-conditions) and [this2](https://vmfocus.com/2018/12/14/azure-cdn-custom-cache-rules/).

Hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to bypass cache in the global cache section as in each deployment the file names are changed and I do not want to change the caching rules after each deployment.

The situation is "cache everything except the response of the root path '/'"